# datetime parsing exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I was finding for taking current date (only date) in datetime datatype.

For that i made some googling and made following code>>

```
DateTime dtCurrDate;
dtCurrDate=DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(),"MM/dd/yyyy",null);
```

This code is giving me exception as :

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

What is mistake within it?

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need that `DateTime.Now.Date` is of DateTime type ? For the error your Shortdate format is not `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Does `DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()` really output something in `MM/dd/yyyy` format?

Comment: I wanted it to compare it with my expDate value in database which is in datetime format.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i dont know, i just tried.

Comment: If you select a `DateTime` from the database, it comes as a `DateTime` - not as a `string`. So what's the matter here?

Comment: no, i want to compare current date with that value

Comment: If you don't know, why didn't you try before posting?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i tried and then posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? There's only two possible ways to do this: either you select the date and compare it in C#, then you only have two `DateTime` values when you do it right. The other way is to do it on database level - then you pass the `DateTime` as a parameter and do the comparison of two `DATETIME` values in SQL.

Comment: comparing is not my problem, i know how to compare. just issue is datetime datatype.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` should be enough for your purpose. `Date` returns only the date component of the DateTime instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are aware of [DateTime.Now.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property, which would give the current date with time set to `00:00:00`.

Now why are you having problem in parsing:

Probably because of your current culture, [`DateTime.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) would give you (for `en-US` culture):

```
Displaying short date for en-US culture: 
//          6/1/2009 (Short Date String)
```

and later you are parsing with: `"MM/dd/yyyy"` you need single digit `M` and `d`

So the code would be:

```
dtCurrDate=DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(),"M/d/yyyy",null);
```

It would be better if you can store the result of `ToShortDateString()` in a string and then check what kind of format you get, and then parse accordingly.

Comment: What is showing you time ? `DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()` ?? or after parsing you are getting Time in `dtCurrDate` ?

Comment: @Freelancer, `dtCurrDate` is `DateTime` type object, that means it will hold the time, There is no data type in C# that holds the Date part independently. Currently it will be set to `12:00 AM` or `00:00`

Comment: @Freelancer, for displaying purpose you can specify the [custom formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for example `string str =  dtCurrDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: can i get it like this? 22 Mar 2013 ? no / or - in between

Comment: @Freelancer, try `string str = dtCurrDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");`

Comment: You can also use [DateTime.Today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).Date. They return the same value; that is, both have midnight as their `Time` component and `Kind` is `Local` (host computer's local time zone).  
If you want to compare Date, DateTime, and Time values, it is usually best _not_ to convert them to strings unless you explicitly format them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is wrong. you should use "d" for the standard date

> "d"
> Short date pattern.
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 (en-US)
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 15/06/2009 (fr-FR)
>
> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 2009/06/15 (ja-JP)

See [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for refrence

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that `DateTime` as such has no format like `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy`. It is only a matter of your preference of how you want it to be displayed and you can control it via various formats through `ToString()`

You can have your database value parsed as a `DateTime` and then you can just compare only the `Date` part using `<instance>.Date` only (this has time component at midnight 12)

Answer (score 1):

You said in your comments that you want to compare a date in the database with the current date. There are only two possible ways to do this:

1. In C#
2. In the database

**C#**
You'll have to select the value from the database. You get a `DateTime` when you do it correctly, like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DateColumn FROM Table", conn))
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        DateTime datecolumn = reader["DateColumn"] as DateTime? ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        if (dateColumn.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL**
You need to pass the date value to SQL. This must be done using parameterized queries:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("....", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateParameter", DateTime.Now.Date);
    ...
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Date` is actually the current day and the time set to `00:00:00`. Of course, you need to do the comparison in SQL accordingly.

Comment: yeah i used % after date for this purpose because in database time is also present.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dtCurrDate=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```